# I want to convert below json array into array list

Tags: android, arrays, json

This is the link to my webserivce please check out
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwCPG2lI_UeCcXlLUGhibTJEdWs

this is image of the android code 
[android code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vOPch.png)

[image]

please help me

Comment: Use Gson, which helps you for easy conversion

Comment: Please do not post images of code. Images cannot be searched, cannot be copied for testing, and impede accessibility.
Instead, include relevant code as [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Gson gson=new GsonBuilder().create();
     JsonArray myCustomArray = gson.toJsonTree(tag).getAsJsonArray();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

at first you should send `JSONArray` Data inside `JSONObject` then via below codes get and set your list

```
    public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONObject responseJsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                JSONArray arrayJsonObject = responseJsonObject.getJSONArray("items");
                    for (int i = 0; i < arrayJsonObject.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = arrayJsonObject.getJSONObject(i);
                        //Or do somthing with Array Datas 
                    }
                }
              }
```

---

if your array not have name :

```
     JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(String_Result);
```

Comment: my array doesnt have a name

Comment: answer was edited